# Need to increase the height & width of two div simultaneously by jquery

Tags: jquery

hi try to increase the height & width of two div simultaneously by jquery like

```
$("#dialog .ui-dialog").animate({ height: $content.outerHeight(), width: $content.outerWidth() }, 1000,
         function () {
             $("#dialog").removeClass("BusyStyles");
             $content.fadeIn('slow'); 
         });
```

it does not work. so please tell me how can i increase size of two div through animate function simultaneously not one after one. $("#dialog .ui-dialog") here i have to give one div id and another one by class name because my situation is like that. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a comma between the two selectors like this:

```
$("#dialog, .ui-dialog").animate({
    height: $content.outerHeight(),
    width: $content.outerWidth() },
    1000,
    function () {
        $("#dialog").removeClass("BusyStyles");
        $content.fadeIn('slow'); 
    }
});
```

I hope it helps!